# How is <navigation> a valid HTML5 tag?

Tags: html, tags

#### Background Info:

I am following along with a Lynda tutorial and the instructor used < navigation > tags for creating his navigation section.

A condensed version of his code:

```
<html>
<body>
  <header>
    <h1>Global Bank</h1>
  </header>

  <navigation>   <=== Valid?
     <ul><li>Menu</li><ul>
  </navigation>  <=== Valid?

  <footer>
  </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

#### My Problem

However, I don't know how this is possible. I know that a navigation section is created by using the < nav > tag, not < navigation >.

I looked through these following places before asking - [the W3C HTML5 Documentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/html/), [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_nav.asp), [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=%3Cnavigation%3E%20tag%20html5&oq=%3Cnav&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j69i59l3j35i39l2.3397j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), and on here.

But all I see is using < nav > to create a navigation section, nothing with < navigation >.

Normally, I would look past this as maybe a mistake of some kind, but the editor that the instructor is using (Atom) was able to identify < navigation > as an HTML tag AND the instructor says that the tag is HTML5. But I am unable to find anything on this < navigation > tag.

#### My Question(s):

Does anyone know where I can find information on < navigation > tag, if any? A link would be appreciated.

If not, how would it be possible for < navigation > to be a valid HTML5 tag, as the instructor said? Is there some way of having user-defined tags? If this is possible, a link with details on this would also be appreciated.

Thank you very much for your time and attention!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you point out, `<navigation>` is not a HTML5 tag, but [`<nav>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/nav) is. Why your teacher would use the custom `<navigation>` instead of the standard `<nav>`, I don't know.

The HTML specification allows the use of custom elements, as it is [explained here](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/custom-elements.html#custom-elements):

> Custom elements provide a way for authors to build their own fully-featured DOM elements. Although authors could always use non-standard elements in their documents, with application-specific behavior added after the fact by scripting or similar, such elements have historically been non-conforming and not very functional. By defining a custom element, authors can inform the parser how to properly construct an element and how elements of that class should react to changes.
>
> Custom elements are part of a larger effort to "rationalise the platform", by explaining existing platform features (like the elements of HTML) in terms of lower-level author-exposed extensibility points (like custom element definition). Although today there are many limitations on the capabilities of custom elements—both functionally and semantically—that prevent them from fully explaining the behaviors of HTML's existing elements, we hope to shrink this gap over time.

But those custom elements must have a name following the pattern `[a-z] (PCENChar)* '-' (PCENChar)*` [as specified on the standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/custom-elements.html#valid-custom-element-name). That means that it has to be a letter followed by an undefined number of characters, a hyphen (-) and more characters (more details on the valid characters on the link).

`<navigation>` does not follow that pattern, and if you try on the [HTML validator](https://validator.w3.org/), you will see that it throws an error and indicates that it is not valid HTML.

Comment: Thank you very much for your feedback! Though I am still unsure how the instructor was able to use such a tag, I can do nothing but move forward. Maybe one day, I will find the answer :D!

Comment: @nilajawill you can use any tag you want, when browsers find a tag they don't know they treat it as a `div`. It won't be valid HTML though.

Comment: Hello Alvaro! I noticed that, within the instructor's CSS, he has defined properties for navigation. So what I can understand is, as you said, it possible to "create" a tag, then give it CCS properties and things will work out. However, it will not be valid. I also noticed that if I remove the CSS properties, < navigation > no longer works. This is very new and very interesting. Again, I thank you for your feedback!

Answer (score 0):

The  tag defines a set of navigation links.

Ex:

```
    <nav>
       <a href="/html/">HTML</a> |
       <a href="/css/">CSS</a> |
       <a href="/js/">JavaScript</a> |
       <a href="/jquery/">jQuery</a>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have never come across `<navigation>` tag. But you can always create it as a user defined tag. You will get all needed help from :

https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/customelements/